# Quelles seraient d’autres façons de dire « elle n’a pas peur de dire les choses » en parlant d’une personne qui ne se laisse pas faire ?

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

**sans recourir à la tournure « ne pas avoir peur de »

Contrairement à Chantal, tu n’as pas la fermeté requise pour le poste de gérant de bar, tu manques de cran, ou mieux d’audace. Je pense plutôt que tu ferais fi des situations difficiles, adoptant une attitude passive, évitant l’intervention active. Devant les difficultés, elle n’hésiterait pas, elle, à passer à l’action et elle ne resterait pas impassible face aux insultes, aux comportement agressifs et aux confrontations, loin de là! Elle saurait réagir en prenant ses responsabilités en main.

…**Elle n’a pas peur de dire les choses respectueusement et sans contre-attaquer de façon impulsive.** Rares sont les fois où les échanges d’injures ont dégénéré en rixe.

…*Elle n’a pas peur de dire les choses en face* respectueusement et sans contre-attaquer de façon impulsive. Rares sont les fois où les échanges d’injures ont dégénéré en rixe.

…*Elle n’a pas peur de dire tout ce qu’elle a à dire* (à propos d’une personne ou de sa conduite) de manière respectueuse et sans contre-attaquer impulsivement. Rares sont les fois où les échanges d’injures ont dégénéré en rixe.

…*Elle n’a pas peur de dire (le fond de) sa pensée* respectueusement et sans contre-attaquer de manière impulsive. Rares sont les fois où les échanges d’injures ont dégénéré en rixe.

…*Elle n’a pas peur des mots.*

…*Elle n’a pas peur de dire ce qu’elle pense* (d’une personne ou de sa conduite) respectueusement et sans contre-attaquer de manière impulsive. Rares sont les fois où les échanges d’injures ont dégénéré en rixe.

…*Elle n’a pas peur de dire à quelqu’un son fait* dans le respect et sans contre-attaquer de manière impulsive. Rares sont les fois où les échanges d’injures ont dégénéré en rixe.

…*Elle n’a pas peur de dire à quelqu’un ses quatre vérités* respectueusement et sans contre-attaquer de manière impulsive. Rares sont les fois où les échanges d’injures ont dégénéré en rixe.

…*Elle n’a pas peur de dire les choses comme elle les pense* respectueusement et sans contre-attaquer de manière impulsive. Rares sont les fois où les échanges d’injures ont dégénéré en rixe.

…*Elle a le courage de ses opinions et de les exprimer* respectueusement sans contre-attaquer de façon impulsive. Rares sont les fois où les échanges d’injures ont dégénéré en rixe.

---

D’autres formules qui m’ont traversé l’esprit.

…*Elle ose dire librement sa pensée* de façon respectueuse et sans s’emporter en toutes circonstances.

…Elle a *la capacité de s’affirmer et de défendre son point vue* dans le plus grand respect d’autrui en tout temps.

Comment: Elle a l'équanimité de etc.

Comment: Bien franchement c’est la première fois que je lis ce mot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrairement à Chantal, tu n’as pas la fermeté requise pour le poste de gérant de bar, tu manques de cran, ou mieux d’audace. Je pense plutôt que tu **ne t'occuperais pas** des situations difficiles, **en** adoptant une attitude passive, **en** évitant l’intervention active. Devant les difficultés, elle n’hésiterait pas, elle, à passer à l’action et elle ne resterait pas impassible face aux insultes, aux comportement agressifs et aux confrontations, loin de là! Elle saurait réagir en prenant ses responsabilités en main.

(1/ faire fi de : mépriser, dédaigner (Wiktionnaire) ; est-ce une personne qui a la particularité de mépriser ce qui est difficile ? 2/ proposition participiales : elles doivent avoir un sujet et exprimer l'une des circonstances suivantes : le temps, la cause, la concession, la condition.)

Dans  toutes ces phrases l'idée principale est qu'il faut du courage pour s'exprimer *respectueusement*, et je ne pense pas que ce soit ce que quelqu'un voudrait dire, tout au moins, normalement. Qu'on me dise qu'il faut du jugement ou certaines autres qualités serait dans les limites de ce qui est discutable. Il n'est pas vraiment possible de construire sur cette base, puisque le faire serait la légitimer. Cet inconvénient mis à part, toutes les phrases sont convenables, mais elles n'ont pas toutes la même signification.  « Dire son fait à quelqu'un » et « dire ses quatres vérités à quelqu'un » signifient « critiquer quelqu'un sévèrement à propos de leur conduite personnelle ».

- …Elle n’a pas peur de dire les choses, **et cela elle le fait** respectueusement et sans contre-attaquer de façon impulsive. Rares sont les fois où les échanges d’injures ont dégénéré en rixe.
- …Elle n’a pas peur de dire les choses en face, **et cela elle le fait** respectueusement et sans contre-attaquer de façon impulsive. Rares sont les fois où les échanges d’injures ont dégénéré en rixe.
- …Elle n’a pas peur de dire tout ce qu’elle a à dire (à propos d’une personne ou de sa conduite), **et cela elle le fait** de manière respectueuse et sans contre-attaquer impulsivement. Rares sont les fois où les échanges d’injures ont dégénéré en rixe.
- …Elle n’a pas peur de dire (le fond de) sa pensée, **et cela elle le fait** respectueusement et sans contre-attaquer de manière impulsive. Rares sont les fois où les échanges d’injures ont dégénéré en rixe.
- …Elle n’a pas peur des mots.
- …Elle n’a pas peur de dire ce qu’elle pense (d’une personne ou de sa conduite), **et cela elle le fait** respectueusement et sans contre-attaquer de manière impulsive. Rares sont les fois où les échanges d’injures ont dégénéré en rixe.
- …Elle n’a pas peur de dire à quelqu’un son fait, **et cela elle le fait** dans le respect et sans contre-attaquer de manière impulsive. Rares sont les fois où les échanges d’injures ont dégénéré en rixe.
- …Elle n’a pas peur de dire à quelqu’un ses quatre vérités, **et cela elle le fait** respectueusement et sans contre-attaquer de manière impulsive. Rares sont les fois où les échanges d’injures ont dégénéré en rixe.
- …Elle n’a pas peur de dire les choses comme elle les pense, **et cela elle le fait** respectueusement et sans contre-attaquer de manière impulsive. Rares sont les fois où les échanges d’injures ont dégénéré en rixe.
- …Elle a le courage de ses opinions et de les exprimer, **et cela elle le fait** respectueusement sans contre-attaquer de façon impulsive. Rares sont les fois où les échanges d’injures ont dégénéré en rixe.
- …Elle ose dire librement sa pensée, **et cela elle le fait** de façon respectueuse et sans s’emporter en toutes circonstances.
- …Elle a la capacité de s’affirmer et de défendre son point vue, **et cela elle le fait** dans le plus grand respect d’autrui en tout temps.

*Une addition*

- …Elle ne *s'en laisse pas conter*, mais elle conserve une attitude respectueuse en se gardant de contre-attaques impulsives. Rares sont les fois où les échanges d’injures ont dégénéré en rixe.

---

***Addition en réponse à des questions supplémentaires de user Thérèse à lire dans les commentaires***

https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-112389.php

http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/part-gerond.html

https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proposition_participiale

https://www.cordial.fr/grammaire/manuels/PROP_PART.htm

LE PARTICIPE PRÉSENT

Le participe présent est la forme verbale terminée  par « -ant » ; elle marque une action ; elle peut avoir un COD ou un CC ; elle est invariable. La proposition participiale dans laquelle on le trouve a une valeur de proposition subordonnée (relative ou conjonctive).

Le participe (présent ou passé) peut s’utiliser pour remplacer une proposition subordonnée adverbiale (subordonnées appelées souvent aussi « propositions participiales »). Cet emploi est fréquent à l’écrit, mais rare à l’oral. La caractéristique des subordonnées participiales est que le participe a implicitement une valeur adverbiale, et, souvent, la subordonnée n’est pas introduite par une conjonction. Il exprime le plus fréquemment la cause, le temps ou la condition, plus rarement la concession. Cette valeur se déduit du contexte et du sens de la phrase. Le participe remplace donc à la fois un verbe conjugué et une conjonction de subordination :

(1) Comme Aurèle n’avait plus d’argent pour payer son loyer... → Aurèle n’ayant plus d’argent pour payer son loyer... (*cause*)
(2) comme mes voisins ont déménagé en octobre, je suis seul dans la maison. → Mes voisins ayant déménagé, je suis seul depuis octobre.
(3) Comme il n’avait plus d’argent… → N’ayant plus d’argent… (*cause*)
(4) Quand ils furent enfin rentrés de voyage… → Étant enfin rentrés de voyage… (*temps*)

La proposition subordonnée participiale est une proposition qui n'est introduite par aucun mot subordonnant [sauf exception]. Elle est séparée du verbe de la proposition principale par un signe de ponctuation (virgule, tirets ou parenthèses). Par ailleurs, elle est mobile dans la phrase.

Il ne faut pas confondre le participe, noyau d'une proposition, et le participe en apposition, celui-ci n'a pas de sujet propre, il joue un rôle d'adjectif.

- Le médecin a ausculté la jeune femme souffrant d'amnésie.= qui souffre
- La jeune femme, souffrante, se rendit chez le médecin.= malade

Quand la participiale a un sens concessif, elle est généralement introduite par une conjonction :

- Nous avons beaucoup aimé l’accueil, le menu et les activités proposées, bien que n’ayant pas eu le temps d’en profiter au maximum.
- Les deux démarches, quoique relevant de la même volonté de refonder l’Union européenne, sont donc bien distinctes.

Le participe peut avoir un sujet exprimé , qui peut être un groupe nominal ou un pronom à la forme pleine, mais pas un pronom faible (je tu etc.).

Quand le sujet de la proposition adverbiale est le même que celui de la principale (coréférence du sujet), il n’est pas exprimé devant le participe. Dans ce cas-là, dans l’exemple ci-dessus (« n’ayant plus d’argent »), le participe englobe donc 1) la conjonction de subordination « comme », 2) le sujet « il », 3) le verbe « avoir ».

Comme les autres propositions adverbiales, la proposition subordonnée participiale peut être antéposée à la principale, ou postposée. À l’écrit, elle est normalement toujours séparée de la principale par une virgule.

Toutes les participiales peuvent être transformées en subordonnées adverbiales introduites par une conjonction ; mais l’inverse n’est pas toujours possible.

LE GÉRONDIF

Le gérondif est la forme adverbiale du verbe. Sa forme est « en <participe présent du verbe> ». Comme l'adverbe, il explicite le verbe dans la phrase. Alors que le participe présent qualifie un nom ou un pronom, le gérondif modifie un verbe. La préposition « en » n'est pas optionnelle. Elle ne peut être omise que très exceptionnellement dans un tour idiomatique.

> (LBU) Aller EN DIMINUANT, *ou* aller diminuant (omission idiomatique de « en »)
> Le gérondif a un rapport privilégié avec le sujet : « Je les ai vus EN REVENANT de la gare. » ne sgnifie pas du tout la même chose que  « Je les ai vus REVENANT de la gare. ».
> (LBU § 820 e) *Aller* **suivi d'un gérondif** marque l'aspect duratif, la continuité
> de l'action. Le gérondif peut être précédé ou non de *en*.
> Certains estiment qu'avec *en*, *aller* conserve quelque chose de sa valeur d'action et est moins nettement auxiliaire ; mais, dans la plupart des cas, cette nuance n'est pas sensible :
> ♦ La tempête va s'apaisant (litt.) ou en s'apaisant (Ac. 2001).
> Avec *grandissant* et surtout *croissant*, la construction sans *en* reste tout à fait courante.
> […]
> Les deux constructions existent aussi quand *être* est mis pour *aller* (§ 833, b) :
> ♦ La plupart des difficultés ONT ÉTÉ s'aggravant, de saison en saison (DUHAMEL, Paroles de médecin, p. 130).
> ♦ En dépit des critiques, le succès de Littré A ÉTÉ en s'affirmant (G. MATORÉ, Hist. des dictionn.fr., p. 124)

Pour employer le gérondif il faut que le sujet du verbe de la proposition dans laquelle se trouve le gérondif, soit aussi le sujet du gérondif.

Les valeurs adverbiales du gérondif sont le temps, la simultanéité, la manière, la condition, la cause, l'opposition et la concession.

- Je l'ai salué en passant. (temps)
- Elle tricote en regardant la télévision. (simultanéité)
- Le vase s'est brisé en tombant. (manière)
- En ne disant pas un mot, vous consentez. (condition)
- Il s'est blessé en reprenant l'entraînement trop tôt. (cause)
- Même en réfléchissant vraiment, il n'a pas trouvé la solution.

C'est bizarre, je ne trouve pas « Julien … adorant paysages familiers. ». Néanmoins, cette construction ne correspond ni à la cause ni au temps. C'est probablement du français canadien qui provient de l'anglais. Il n'y a pas de thème dans cette proposition participiale (sujet).

Voici ce qu'on peut lire dans la [Grammaire du français](https://tribu-sup.phm.education.gouv.fr/portal/share/BCBgmg) p. 153.

> Le participe présent est une forme verbale qui s’emploie ou bien avec une valeur verbale (Les invités arrivant, je m’empresse de dresser la table), ou bien avec une valeur d’adjectif (une élève aimant la lecture [= amatrice de lecture] ; une idée intéressante) ou bien avec une valeur d’adverbe (Elle est entrée en faisant du bruit [= bruyamment]).
> Lorsqu’il est en emploi verbal, le participe présent est le noyau du GV de la proposition participiale : Les invités arrivant, je m’empresse de dresser la table.

Dans le dernier exemple la notion de *cause* est mise en valeur (« Je m'empresse de dresser la table *parce que* les invités arrivent. »).

1/ La notion d'allègement (« moins lourdes »)  d'une construction par la suppression de « en » lorsque ce mot précède un participe présent est entièrement fausse. Cela se déduit des principes qui ont été rassemblés ci-dessus.

2/ Julien a photographié sa région sous tous les angles, adorant ces paysages familiers.

Il faut comprendre que « adorant ces paysages familier » ne peut être qu'une proposition participiale ; il doit exister une relation entre le verbe de la subordonnée et celui de la principale ; d'après ce qui est dit des propositions participiales dont le verbe est un participe présent, la relation doit être la cause, ou le temps ou la condition., et on doit pouvoir déduire cette valeur du contexte.
(petite digression) Il ne peut pas être question d'une conjonction.

- Jean se promenait, regardant les fleurs. *ou* Regardant les fleurs, Jean se promenait. (*Ce n'est pas correct parce que la proposition participiale est une *subordonnée*,  pas un indépendante qui permettrait simplement d'ajouter une idée ; l'idée doit être connectée à celle de la principale.*)

La conjonction d'idées indépendante serait obtenue au moyen d'un gérondif, mais il n'est plus question de deux propositions dans ce cas (il n'y a dans cette phrase qu'une seule proposition).

- Jean se promenait en regardant les fleurs. (*correct*) (fin de digression)

Le problème n'est plus grammatical à ce point mais sémantique : l'adoration n'est pas une cause évidente amenant un individu à faire des photos. Dans un tel cas l'utilisateur avisé du langage aura recours à une conjonction.

- Comme il adorait les paysages familiers de cette région, Julien l'a photographiée sous tous ses angles.

On a ici un exemple du principe de non équivalence des participiales avec les conjonctives. (Toutes les participiales peuvent être transformées en subordonnées adverbiales introduites par une conjonction ; mais l’inverse n’est pas toujours possible.)

3/ « …il arrive souvent que je lise de telles phrases qui s’en passent et qui me donnent l’impression qu’elles sont moins lourdes. »

Il est possible qu'il s'agisse du français du Canada ou peut-être du type de français où se trouvent ces phrases, un français moderne peut-être par des auteurs à l'esprit trop libre… et même influencés de façon désordonnée par l'anglais.

4/ « fil qui débute par « je ne suis pas d’accord… », je ne parviens pas à saisir ce que vous voulez dire. »

Il me semble qu'il n'y a aucune relation entre le courage et ce dont parlent ces psychologues. Essentiellement, il peut s'agir de faire un effort, faire preuve de sagesse, de subtilité, de patience, etc. Tout cela fait partie des demandes quotidiennes sur l'intellect qui n'ont rien à voir avec la peur ;  le courage est ce qui permet de dominer la peur ou la grande lassitude.

Comment: L’idée principale que je voulais faire passer est qu’il faut du courage pour s’exprimer franchement, non pas du courage pour s’exprimer respectueusement.

Comment: https://www.psychologies.com/amp/Moi/Moi-et-les-autres/Relationnel/Articles-et-Dossiers/Bien-communiquer-c-est-avoir-le-courage-de-dire-les-choses

Comment: S’exprimer franchement (dire à quelqu’un ce qu’on pense de lui ou de sa conduite) de manière respectueuse sans agressivité.

Comment: Plutôt que de se laisser faire, de ne pas réagir.

Comment: https//fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assertivité

Comment: Les « en » que vous avez ajoutés devant les participes présents sont-ils facultatifs ou obligatoires ?

Comment: @Thérèse  « courage pour s’exprimer franchement » : oui, peut-être, ça peut se discuter. Je ne suis pas d'accord avec cette première référence; « dire les choses simplement, sans vexer » peut demander du tact, voire  de la bonté, mais peut-on avoir le courage d'avoir du tact ou d'être bon ? Je ne comprend pas du tout ces notions.

Comment: @Thérèse Selon ce que je crois comprendre, il n'y a pas d'autres possibilité que d'utiliser des gérondifs ; sans « en » ces participes présent ne correspondent pas à quoi que ce soit. https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proposition_participiale  https://ameliorer-ses-ecrits.univ-cotedazur.fr/wp-content/ressources/PHRASES.publi/auroraW/co/02_EmploiPP.html

Comment: Mettons en parallèle la phrase en objet (avec participe présent) et une phrase tirée de votre deuxième référence: « Julien a photographié sa région sous tous les angles, adorant ces paysages familiers. Pourquoi, à l’instar de cette dernière, ne peut-on pas omettre les « en ». J’ai omis les « en » car il arrive souvent que je lis de telles phrases qui s’en passent et me donnent l’impression qu’elles sont moins lourdes.

Comment: Pour ce qui est de votre premier commentaire qui fait suite aux miens dans ce fil qui débute par « je ne suis pas d’accord… », je ne parviens pas à saisir ce que vous voulez dire.

Comment: Ce que je cherche à dire, c’est que Chantal, contrairement à l’autre personne concernée, a l’audace de dire ce qu’elle a à dire, qu’elle a le courage d’oser exprimer sa pensée, par exemple ce qu’elle pense du comportement d’une personne, sans pour autant tomber dans l’agressivité. Bref, elle a la capacité de s’affirmer, alors que l’autre personne en objet aurait tendance à se taire et à ne pas broncher, elle préférerait rester passif devant des situations difficiles, pour ne las dire qu’elle les fuirait. Comme on dit par chez moi, cette dernière ne mettrait pas ses culottes!

Comment: **rester passive.

Comment: @Thérèse Je vais essayer de rendre cela plus clair; cependant, il me faudra un peu temps avant que je puisse faire une addition dans ma réponse (l'espace commentaire est trop petit).

Comment: D’accord, j’attendrai patiemment et vivement la modification (addition) de votre réponse!

Comment: Je ne trouve rien à redire: l’ajout est excellent.

Comment: Soucieux de convaincre le profane, il le guide dans des domaines réputés inaccessibles, lui **faisant** constater l'existence d'univers parallèles comme meilleure explication du comportement de la lumière, lui **faisant** voir le calcul informatique comme l'embryon d'une réalité virtuelle, ou les promesses des ordinateurs quantiques comme fondées sur la distribution du travail entre univers parallèles, ou même la vie comme une structure régulière du multi-univers, **l'entraînant** enfin dans de fascinantes expériences de pensée à propos du voyage dans le temps.

Comment: https://www.amazon.fr/LÉtoffe-réalité-David-Deutsch/dp/2842250249

Comment: J'ai déjà mentionné que je remarque régulièrement l'absence du préfixe "en" devant un participe présent. Ce texte en est un exemple concret.

Comment: @Antivlad Vous « remarquez »… Est-ce à dire que que vous constatez qu'il manque à tort ? Non, pas nécessairement. Plutôt, vous constatez que dans certains cas il n'est pas utilisé (ce qui peut être à tort où tout simplement parce ni gérondif ni participe présent ne conviennent ou encore parce que les deux alternatives sont possibles (avec des sens différents). Dans chaque cas que vous trouvez il faut que vous fassiez l'analyse jusqu'à ce que le processus devienne ancré dans votre esprit et vous permette ainsi d'utiliser ces deux constructions rapidement. (1/3)

Comment: @Antivlad Je vais vous donner des indications, mais une discussion prolongée n'a sa place ni dans les commentaires ni dans ma réponse, puisque dans cette dernière il s'agirait de répétition ou d'exercice. Il faudra donc passer par la page discussion (Chez Causette). Dans la longue  phrase que vous citez  les deux sont possibles. **I** pp connecté à « il » − remplaçable par  « comme - verbe » (III.− Comme morph. temporel., https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/comme) notion temps exprimée (« comme il lui (l') <verbe> … ») temps déduit du contexte (cause et condition non logique)  — (2/3)

Comment: @Antivlad  **II** auteur  choisit pp (**I**)  mais s'il choisit gérondif (possible parce que même sujet verbe principal et bon sens du résultat) sens change (pas une question d'omission sans changer sens, rare)  — gérondif connecté au verbe — verbe « explicité » par adverbe représenté par gérondif  — des diverses valeurs (temps, condition, concession, ) valeur qui se dégage,  manière, à cause de  « soucieux de convaincre » _ manière de guider 3 verbes  — cependant ambigüité possible entre simultanéité et manière (difficile), certains pourraient arguer pour simultanéité. (3/3)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142101/discussion-between-antivlad-and-lph).